# when add new element on list repaint stops for a moment

Tags: java

Java.problem is when i start addding new element repaint stops every time for a moment while timer is working and elements are moving finaly when it repaints elements just jump like thay have been moving all this time.also there is throwing strange exeption.  some code:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
   g = (Graphics2D) g;

   g.drawImage(img1, 0, 0,null);
   Iterator<zombie> it = zombies.iterator();
   while(it.hasNext())
   {
      if(it.next().heals <= 0)
      {
         it.remove();
      }
      else{
         g.drawImage(it.next().img  ,it.next().x , it.next().y , null);
      }
   }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
   Iterator<zombie> it = zombies.iterator();
   while(it.hasNext())
   {
      it.next().move();
   }
   repaint();
}
```

that is new thread  that generates new items:

```
public void run()
{
   Random rd = new Random();
   while(true)
   {    
      try {
         Thread.sleep(1000 + rd.nextInt(2000));

         if(rd.nextInt(4) == 1)
         {
            zombies.add(new ZombieLow(1000,rd.nextInt(500),1,20,300));
         }
         else
         {
            zombies.add(new ZombieHard(1000,rd.nextInt(500),1,15,700));
         }  
      } 
      catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

what is that problem with? if you need more info just say i will give it.

Comment: I think `javax.swing.Timer` will solve your problems, there are many examples on it, try to read the [**Official Documentation**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) first.

Comment: Provided code doesn't help in understanding the problem. Please provide an SSCCE

Comment: i am using that import

Comment: import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

Answer (score 0):

try to put the repaint() method in the while loop. In your case you repaint your Zombie after moving all.
another thing if you use Thread.sleep() in the move method you should make every Zombie in his own Thread.

Hope that helps, Salam =)

Comment: it doesnt  help it just move ma zombie than stops after 5 sec there became 2 zombies but my first zombie just jumps forwar and that aktion repeats always zombies becomes more an more but firstly befor make new one all stops on frame but it movese realy we just dont see that . what could be the problem with?